# PHP and MySQL Search getting Full Data From Database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying with search and get data from database but unable to complete this task as a new kid for this php and MySQL.

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", ""); // Establishing Connection with Server
$db = mysql_select_db("vdl", $connection); // Selecting Database
//MySQL Query to read data
$query = mysql_query("select * from digital_library", $connection);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
echo '<ul>';
echo "<li><b><a href=\"read.php?id={$row['company_id']}\">{$row['company_name']}</a></b></li>";
echo "<br />";
echo '</ul>';
}
?>
```

These are the fields I am going to get from database. Trying with simple search but not working to get full data.

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
$id = $_GET['id'];
$query1 = mysql_query("select * from digital_library where company_id=$id", $connection);
while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($query1)) {
?>

    <span>Company Name: </span> <?php echo $row1['company_name']; ?><br><br>
    <span>Since: </span> <?php echo $row1['since']; ?><br><br>
    <span>Strength: </span> <?php echo $row1['strength']; ?><br><br>
    <span>Head Quarters: </span> <?php echo $row1['head_quarter']; ?><br><br>
    <span>Location (City): </span> <?php echo $row1['locations']; ?><br><br>
    <span>Develpment Centers: </span> <?php echo $row1['development_centers']; ?><br><br>
    <span>Customers: </span> <?php echo $row1['customers']; ?><br><br>
    <span>MNC: </span> <?php echo $row1['mnc']; ?><br><br>
    <span>CMMI: </span> <?php echo $row1['cmmi']; ?><br><br>
    <span>Domains: </span> <?php echo $row1['domains']; ?><br><br>
    <span>Industries: </span> <?php echo $row1['industries']; ?><br><br>
    <span>Domain Competitors: </span> <?php echo $row1['domain_competitor']; ?><br><br>
    <span>Products: </span> <?php echo $row1['products']; ?><br><br>
    <span>Services: </span> <?php echo $row1['services']; ?><br><br>
    <span>Uniqueness: </span> <?php echo $row1['uniqueness']; ?><br><br>
    <span>Company URL: </span> 
    <a target='_blank' href="<?php echo $row1['url']; ?>"> 
        <?php echo $row1['url']; ?>
    </a><br><br>
    <!--<span>Comapny Logo:</span> <?php echo $row1['logo']; ?><br><br>-->
    <span>Onsight: </span> <?php echo $row1['onsight']; ?><br><br>
    <span>Benefits: </span> <?php echo $row1['benefits']; ?><br><br>
    <span>Awards: </span> <?php echo $row1['awards']; ?><br><br>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Could you post the result of your query?

Comment: If you're just starting out, find a newer tutorial, the `mysql_` extension is obsolete.

Comment: share your result for the query

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT company_name, url FROM vdl WHERE digital_library;`

Comment: **WARNING** `mysql_` functions have been deprecated and have been completely removed since PHP7. Use `mysqli_` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Google help me to Solve my question.

```
<?php
mysql_connect ("localhost", "root","")  or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("vdl");

$term = $_POST['term'];

$sql = mysql_query("select * from digital_library where company_name like '%$term%'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    echo 'ID: '.$row['company_id'];
    echo '<br/> First Name: '.$row['company_name'];
    echo '<br/> Since: '.$row['since'];
    echo '<br/> Strength: '.$row['strength'];
    echo '<br/> Head Quarters: '.$row['head_quarter'];
    echo '<br/> Location (City): '.$row['locations'];
    echo '<br/> Development Centers: '.$row['development_centers'];
    echo '<br/> Customers: '.$row['customers'];
    echo '<br/> MNC: '.$row['mnc'];
    echo '<br/> CMMI: '.$row['cmmi'];
    echo '<br/> Domains: '.$row['domains'];
    echo '<br/> Industries: '.$row['industries'];
    echo '<br/> Domain Competitors: '.$row['domain_competitor'];
    echo '<br/> Products: '.$row['products'];
    echo '<br/> Services: '.$row['services'];
    echo '<br/> Uniqueness: '.$row['uniqueness'];
    echo '<br/> URL: '.$row['url'];
    echo '<br/> Onsights: '.$row['onsight'];
    echo '<br/> Benefits: '.$row['benefits'];
    echo '<br/> Awards: '.$row['awards'];
    echo '<br/><br/>';
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query1 = mysql_query("select * from digital_library where company_name like '%$comany_name%', $connection);
```